# GhostHunter Number of posts found: 0 issue

Tags: ghost-blog, ghost

I'm using Ghost blog system and GhostHunter as searching engine. But when I search **anything** it returns me `Number of posts found: 0`.

Who knows, how to fix it?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. I found out that it's because the search form's URL is wrong (lacking the `/ghost/api/v0.1` part) and thus instead of getting json data, it's getting a 404.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/jamalneufeld/ghostHunter/issues/11) I was getting the `Ghost is not defined` error message on the console in F12 dev tools.

I simply had to enable the `Public API` checkbox on the `Labs` tab under Settings on the Ghost Admin page.

For reference my script is:

```
$("#search-field").ghostHunter({
    rss: "{{@blog.url}}/rss/",
    results: "#results"
});
```